# Too many arguments to return

Tags: go, singleton

I have this golang file:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"

    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
)

var db *sqlx.DB
var once sync.Once

// GetDBConnection whatever
func GetDBConnection() {

    once.Do(func() {
        db, err := sqlx.Connect("postgres", "user=tom dbname=jerry password=myPassword sslmode=disable")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
    })

    return db   // <<< error here

}
```

I get this error:

> `Too many arguments to return`

I am just trying to create a singleton pattern and return the db connection. I am not sure if what is returned from sqlx.Connect is type sqlx.DB, that might be the problem. Is there a quick way to determine the return type of `sqlx.Connect()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared the function `GetDBConnection()` to return no arguments.

```
func GetDBConnection() {
```

[You have to tell Go](https://tour.golang.org/basics/4) the type of the argument you intend to return:

```
func GetDBConnection() *sqlx.DB {
```

As for determining the type, I just went to [look at the source code](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx/blob/master/sqlx.go#L633). You could also look at the [documentation on godoc.org](https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#Connect), which is auto-generated from publicly available Go packages.

Comment: thanks after that fix, I get "db declared but not used" that's a weird one

Comment: Have you taken the Tour of Go yet? You should stop and do that. These are very basic, new-to-the-language questions.

Comment: Eh, I should be able to google this and get an answer to it. If google doesn't have the answer, I come to SO. Reading the docs doesn't usually help me, but I will try. I get a lot of information to questions I don't currently have.

Comment: Yes, Google does indeed have the answer, but we always recommend the Tour of Go because Go does quite a few things very differently from other languages, and taking ten minutes to go through it and play with the examples will save you a lot of time later on.

Comment: The Tour of Go will give you all the fundamentals, including the answer to this question and many others. Probably 90% of Go questions on SO are answered within the Tour, and it only takes a few minutes to complete.

Comment: @Adrian it's better to create questions on SO that are tagged with the name of the error...then golang newbs can search for them...reading the docs and getting 100s of answers to questions you don't currently have is not how learning happens unfortunately. The docs help for reference - but it would be nice if they had the error and then explanations for the error so people could search quickly.

Comment: @MrCholo Most people _do_ learn much from the Tour of Go. It's unfortunate that you don't believe you would be one of them. People around here tend to react negatively when they read basic questions that were answered in the Tour.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I will admit the OP was dumb, I have worked with like 2 statically typed languages before, but whether it should have been `func GetDBConnection() *sqlx.DB {` or `func GetDBConnection() sqlx.DB {` (without the asterisk), would the Tour really have given me a quick answer to that? prolly not